# TranslationEditorBundle export: There is no dumper associated with format ""

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use https://github.com/servergrove/TranslationEditorBundle

My config_dev.yml:

```
server_grove_translation_editor:
  storage:
    type: server_grove_translation_editor.storage.orm
    manager: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

I go to `/app_dev.php/translations/editor`, add some translations, and run:

```
./app/console locale:editor:export
```

I get this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                     
  There is no dumper associated with format "".
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show value of your `locale` parameter?

Comment: in config.yml i have default_locale: pl

Comment: Try to report this issue in TranslationEditorBundle github issue tracker. I think maintainer should help you